# Regex : extract a 27 long char substring surrounded by ""

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract a 27 char long substring, `DpIJr_dR-DNu5kcR9RGmRprcnGU`, from the following text with `regex`

> text = '[[\"jewelry_designer\"]\n,[\"watch_store\"]\n,[\"jewelry_appraiser\"]\n,[\"leather_goods_store\"]\n]\n,null,\"**DpIJr_dR-DNu5kcR9RGmRprcnGU**\",null,null,null,[null]'

So far I isolated strings surrounded by `\"` with the following

```
pattern = '\\"(.*?)\\"'
output = re.findall(pattern, text)
### output => ['jewelry_designer', 'watch_store', 'jewelry_appraiser', 'leather_goods_store', 'DpIJr_dR-DNu5kcR9RGmRprcnGU']
```

My next step is to add a length constraint to my output, so it only matches 27 characters long substrings.

I tried `\\"(.*?){27}\\"` or `\\"(.*?{27})\\"` but not successfully. I could do `[x for x in output if len(x) == 27]`, but it would be a shame.

Comment: Use `(.{0,27}?)` instead of `(.*?){27}` to match 0 to 27 chars but as few as possible, or, `([^"]{27})` if exactly 27 chars must match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `(.{27}?)` did the trick in this situation

Comment: `(.{27}?)` = `(.{27})` and it will over match the attribute value. You must use `([^"]{27})`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for the clarification, I should definitively improve my `regex` syntax comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
\\\"([^\"]{27})\\\"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9CVlgJ/1)

You first match `\"` with `\\\"`, then match and capture the string you're interested in `[^\"]{27}` (anything but quote repeated 27 times) and then again `\"` with `\\\"`